# Render an Element on Fullscreen Video.js in React App?

Tags: css, reactjs, video, sass, video.js

**ORIGINAL POST HAS BEEN EDITED: I am working with Video.js in a React app. I need badges to appear on the video player at various points during the video based on a state change. The problem is, when I enter full screen mode, the video sits on top of the badges. I have the Z-index for both badges set to the max, and they still do not show.

I've tried using a video overlay library, but I need the badges to render on particular state changes, and I'm having difficulty getting the overlay function to read the state change. I've attempted to add a class with the Video.js player.on('fullscreenchange') event, but have been unsuccessful with that as well. Any insight on how to get the badges to display while in fullscreen would be very much appreciated.

Relevant JSX code:

```
    class VideoPage extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          defaultPlayerOptions: {
            autoplay: false,
            controls: true,
            responsive: true,
            sources: [{
              src: "",
            }],
            isAdRolling: false,
            playbackRates: [0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
          },
          liveVideoPlaying: false,
        }
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     // overlay code here though it is not registering the state change. including it only for reference. 

     player.overlay(() =>{
       if(liveVideoPlaying){
         content: 'Live'
      }
     else if (isAdRolling){
         content: 'overlay ad'
      }
   // the player is instantiated and then I've got the below:
   player.on('fullscreenchange', function (e){
          if(player.isFullscreen()){
            player.addClass('full-screen-badge')
          }
        })
}

render(){
 <div className='video-player-bkgrnd'>
        <div className='video-container'>
          <div className='videoplayer'>
          <div className={isAdRolling ? 'ad-badge-wrapper': ''}>
                <AdBadge/>
           </div>
           <div className={!isAdRolling && liveVideoPlaying ? 'live- 
           badge-wrapper': ''}>
                <LiveBadge/>
            </div> 
            <video ref={node=>this.player_node=node} className='video- 
            js'>
                <source src={videoURL}>
                </source>
            </video>
         </div>

}
```

Relevant SCSS code:

```
.videoplayer {
      .ad_badge {
          position: relative;
          top: -45rem;
          left: 10rem;
          z-index: 2147483647;

      }    
      .live-badge {
          position: absolute;
          top: -45rem;
          left: 76rem;
          z-index: 2147483647;
      }
  }
  .video-js{
        width: 1170px;
        height: 660px;
        margin: 121px 135px 79px 135px;
        box-shadow: 0 20px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a video.js component which was delivered inside a React application. I was able to create an overlay, but when I created an overlay to be rendered inside the ModalDialog component of videoJS, I kinda lost myself.

Let's say that `<Overlay />` is my component. It has some dynamic data, as you probably would expect from a React element. In fact, it loads a remote JSON which is supposed to define its content.

Now, I've tried to put the content inside the modal by loading the component in these 3 ways:

1. using renderToString

   ```
   this.modal.contentEl().innerHTML = renderToString(
     <PollOverlay questionId={54} />
   );
   ```

I knew it wouldn't work as this is supposed to be rendered server side, however I was just checking and if the content isn't dynamic, it would indeed render a "static" react component.

So I guess an idea would be to change the static content and then feed it to the component.

2. loading the component as innerHTML directly.

   ```
   this.modal.contentEl().innerHTML = <PollOverlay questionId={54} />;
   ```

Obviously this wouldn't work but I was just curious. This way I get a nice [Object Object] rendered on the overlay. And the close button, of course.

3. using ReactDom.render

   ```
   ReactDom.render(<PollOverlay questionId={54} />, this.modal.contentEl());
   ```

This way it works! I hope it helps.